# Formatting the data in python

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am making the rest request using the Python -request library .

API is accepting the data in folowing format

```
aspected_data = 
    {
      "UseAgentBreakdown": false,
      "Activities": ["Lesson 3: Redeem"],
      "ReportLevel": 
                      {
                          "ParentLevel": [
                                          {
                                              "LevelID": "myretail",
                                              "Level": "COL_NUM8_VAL"
                                        }
                                        ],
                        "CurrentLevel": "COL_NUM5_VAL",
                        "NameField": "COL_NUM5_VAL"
                    }
    }
```

But my code is generating the data something like .

```
data =     {'UseAgentBreakdown': 'False', 'Activities': u"['Lesson 3: Redeem']", 'ReportLevel': u"{'ParentLevel': [{'LevelID': 'myretail', 'Level': 'COL_NUM8_VAL'}], 'CurrentLevel': 'COL_NUM5_VAL', 'NameField': 'COL_NUM5_VAL'}"}
```

Basically This is how I generating the data

```
   data = { "Activities" : learningtype,
                 "UseAgentBreakdown": str(agentbreakdown),
                 "ReportLevel" : reportlevel
                 }
```

where

```
print learnertype   o/p is     ['Lesson 3: Redeem']
print agentbreakdown o/p is   False
print reportlevel    o/p is {'ParentLevel': [{'LevelID': 'myretail', 'Level': 'COL_NUM8_VAL'}], 'CurrentLevel': 'COL_NUM5_VAL', 'NameField': 'COL_NUM5_VAL'}
```

I tried dumping the data using `json.dumps(data)`  which is also not helping me .Please help me out how can I  generate the above format .

Comment: @traceur actually  single qoute and u"['Lesson 3: Redeem']"   (extra double quote is  creating problems )

Answer (score 0):

I do not see a difference between the two data values you are skeptical about. Just to be sure you can check if the interpreter thinks they are different, by doing:

```
data =     {'UseAgentBreakdown': 'False', 'Activities': u"['Lesson 3: Redeem']", 'ReportLevel': u"{'ParentLevel': [{'LevelID': 'myretail', 'Level': 'COL_NUM8_VAL'}], 'CurrentLevel': 'COL_NUM5_VAL', 'NameField': 'COL_NUM5_VAL'}"}
a_data =     {'UseAgentBreakdown': 'False', 'Activities': u"['Lesson 3: Redeem']", 'ReportLevel': u"{'ParentLevel': [{'LevelID': 'myretail', 'Level': 'COL_NUM8_VAL'}], 'CurrentLevel': 'COL_NUM5_VAL', 'NameField': 'COL_NUM5_VAL'}"}
data == a_data
```

prints `True`

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems you appear to be having is the data you're trying to use `json.dumps` on contains strings.

If you can get the data for learningtype as a `list`, agentbreakdown as a `bool` and reportlevel as a `dict` `dumps` should give you what you want

```
agentbreakdown = False
activities = [...insert list elements here...]
reportlevel = {...}

data = { "Activities" : learningtype,
             "UseAgentBreakdown": agentbreakdown,
             "ReportLevel" : reportlevel
             }

json.dumps(data, indent=4)
```

gives

```
{
    "UseAgentBreakdown": false,
    "Activities": [
        "Lesson 3: Redeem"
    ],
    "ReportLevel": {
        "ParentLevel": [
            {
                "LevelID": "myretail",
                "Level": "COL_NUM8_VAL"
            }
        ],
        "CurrentLevel": "COL_NUM5_VAL",
        "NameField": "COL_NUM5_VAL"
    }
}
```